# Gradle - run testReport task after test phase of all submodules

Tags: gradle

I have a simple [project with subprojects](https://github.com/frant-hartm/gradle-aggregate-test-report) and I want to generate aggregate report for all tests when I execute `gradle test` command.

I have followed the [gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#subProjectsTestReport) and added following:

```
task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    // make sure this task is run after all subproject test tasks
    mustRunAfter subprojects*.test

    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/allTests")
    // Include the results from the `test` task in all subprojects
    reportOn subprojects*.test
}
```

This works when I execute `gradle test testReport`, but when I execute `gradle test` or `gradle build` in the root project - the task `testReport` is not run.

How do make gradle to run the task without specifying it every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add: `test.finalizedBy 'testReport'` to your build.gradle; just at the root level, doesn't have to be inside any closure.

```
taskX.finalizedBy taskY
```

Will run taskY everytime taskX completes execution successfully.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Your solution gives me following error message: 'Could not find property 'test' on root project 'gradle-test-aggregation'

Comment: I just looked at your code. The task `test` is added by the java plugin, and you're only applying the java plugin to subprojects, so gradle cannot find task `test`. You can either apply plugin to your root project as well, or make the `subprojects` section `allprojects` and this will work.

Comment: I think I understand it now. I don't want to use java plugin in the root project (it would create empty jar and what not). Is there a better way than to manually define 'fake' test and build tasks in root build.gradle to achieve what I want? [updated build.gradle](https://github.com/frant-hartm/gradle-aggregate-test-report/blob/master/build.gradle#L24)